# $(document).ready(function () not triggering again when form is submitted

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog

I have a Jquery script to launch a modal popup window as follows :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.modal_part').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#tn_select').load('OnBoarding.aspx');

});
</script>
```

This works fine first time, however when I submit the form, it is not being called the second time, and as so I am loosing all the css classes and also the form is not loading in a modal window again.

Is there a way to trigger this Jquery again after I submit the form?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: I have defined some css classes

Comment: How is the form submitted?

Comment: simply when ever u submit the form call those two lines again, u can use 'click' or 'submit' event to call them

Comment: @Beetroot I am doing a button submit with an <asp:button>    How can I call them from the c# code behind?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: So if it's a conventional HTML form submission (not ajax) then what is its `action`?

Comment: Have you tried different browsers ?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I have no action defined.  Its an HTML form, however I am submitting it with an <asp:button>  Ie I have a button_Click() defined in the C# code-behind, and according to that, i am doing the validation and submitting

Comment: This is exactly what I mean about ASP.net. It masks the way things actually work.

Comment: I suspect your form is being submitted via ajax and so the page never does a full reload.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot so I have to go the Ajax way right?  and do a postback with Jquery?  Or I can still do my ASP.NET way?

Comment: @MrCode I guess my form is being submitted ASP.NET way, since I am calling the button_Click() method in my code-behind, and as so, the Jquery document.Ready is not being triggered again

Comment: Johann, you don't have to do it either way any more than the other. The important thing is to master ASP and/or drop it and write the code manually.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using update panel
than

try this

after postback call your javascript function

```
   //SCRIPT to refresh when data come from update panel
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
        function EndRequest(sender, args) {
           $('.modal_part').fadeIn('slow');
           $('#tn_select').load('OnBoarding.aspx');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `UpdatePanel` in your page then you need to rebind all the event when AJAX request ends.

```
    function BindEvents(){
        //your code here
    }
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function() {
        BindEvents();
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        BindEvents();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    modal(); // call this wherever necessary

 });

 function modal() {
     $('.modal_part').fadeIn('slow');
     $('#tn_select').load('OnBoarding.aspx');
 }
```

If your form using ajax use modal() on "success" of the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Make a hidden field in your page ...and when you submit the page set the value in it..
again in page load you need to place a check for the value..
in aspx

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfld" runat="server"/>
```

Now in JS :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myval=$("#hdnfld").val();
if(myval=="submitted"){
// this will execute after submit:-// you can add necessary code here :-
    $('.modal_part').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#tn_select').load('OnBoarding.aspx');
    // Set its value again to null;
    $("#hdnfld").val("");
}
else
{
    // This will execute when page will load first time :-
    $('.modal_part').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#tn_select').load('OnBoarding.aspx');
}

});
</script>
```

and in Code Behind:-

```
protected void btn1_clicked(object sender,EventArgs e){
// set the hdn field:-
hdnfld.value="submitted";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using update panel try using the below code:

Try calling jquery function:

```
function pageload(sender, args){
    //jquery code here
}
```

Instead of `document.ready` function.